# What data type should I use as a buffer?

Tags: c++, string, buffer, boost-asio

I'm writing a simple chat server and I'm wondering what data type should I use for a buffer. I was thinking about `string` (which would be quite comfortable in my case), however many times I saw people writing that `string` should not be used as a buffer (better to use `vector<char>`) but is it always the case?

In my program I would like to read some message from the client into a buffer, send that data to some other client and also store that message in database. I use SQLite so, with `string` (skipping db initialization) it would look like this:

```
std::string buffer;
buffer.resize(1024);

// read some data into the buffer
socket.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(&buffer[0], 1024),
    [this, self](boost::system::error_code ec, size_t length)
{
    buffer.resize(length);

    // do some other things with buffer - send to another user ...

    std::string query = "INSERT INTO messages (message) VALUES (\"" + buffer "\")";

    sqlite3_exec(database, query.c_str(), sql_callback, NULL, &err_msg);
}
```

If I was to use `vector<char>` instead, I would firstly need to convert it to a string (or maybe there is another way?)

So what should I use?

Comment: Actually not answering your question, but I would also think about UTF-8 conformity and sql injection (you have presumably taken care of this). In my experience, when dealing with user input, `wstring` avoided a lot of issues with clients.

Comment: For me it would depend on how you are reading the data and how the buffer is going to be used. But if is it going to end up in a `std::string` and you can read directly into that string then I would just use a `std::string`. I would tend to use a `std::vector<char>` for binary data or a temp buffer while reading into a string (or something else).

Comment: Could you please provide the code which reads data into the buffer?

Comment: @StephanLechner I edited my question and provided code for reading into the buffer (I'm using boost::aio)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your use-case mostly requires some "conversion" to `std::string`, then it may be a good idea to simply use `std::string`. The most obvious difference between using `std::string` as a character buffer vs `std::vector<char>` is that the former is permitted to do some magic *Short String Optimization* (depends on library vendor). While the latter isn't permitted to do so. Your Mileage May Vary.

> If I was to use `vector<char>` instead, I would firstly need to convert
>   it to a string (or maybe there is another way?)

Yes you would have to do a `std::vector<char>` to `std::string` "conversion" like this:

```
std::string query = "INSERT INTO messages (message) VALUES (\"" + std::string(buffer.begin(), buffer.end()) + "\")";
```

With some work, you can avoid creating temporaries (and multiple memory allocations) resulting from both buffer "conversion" **and** concatenation using `std::string::operator +`.

```
std::string build_query(const char* left_string, std::size_t left_string_size,
                        const std::vector<char>& buffer,
                        const char* right_string, std::size_t right_string_size)
{
    std::string query;
    query.reserve(left_string_size + buffer.size() + right_string_size + 1);
    query.append(left_string);
    query.append(buffer.begin(), buffer.end());
    query.append(right_string);
    return query;
}
```

And use like:

```
std::vector<char> buffer(24);

constexpr char left[] = "INSERT INTO messages (message) VALUES (\"";
constexpr char right[] = "\")";
std::string query = build_query( left, len(left), buffer, right, len(right) );
```

See a full example here: [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/69f3c734c1f0698f)

On the long run, you could go further and write some neat template helpers to cover more general cases of building up query string from `std::vector<char>`.

As for performance, you will have to measure. Though, while not a valid measure of performance, GCC and Clang actually [emits fewer assembly](https://godbolt.org/g/CHlYPl) instructions for `build_query` than the regular "conversion".